# Manual numbering in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

Is it possible to control chapter/section numbering in bookdown?

e.g.

```
# Introduction {1}
# Theory {14}
# Methods {3}
```

would give the following in the output...

```
1. Introduction
14. Theory
3. Methods
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but I've just bumped into the same issue.

If you **globally** turn off numbering, adding the line

`number_sections: false`

under `bookdown::gitbook:` to your `_output.yml` file, then you can number your chapters and sections in any way you like:

`# 1. Introduction`

`# 14. Theory`

`# 3. Methods`

To repeat: my `_output.yml` file contains the lines

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  number_sections: false
```

Comment: When I render this output as a `git_book` the chapter number is no longer set in bold and I suspect because the number is no longer different from the title. In the `pdf_book` (and a custom style class) the difference is even more prominent.

Comment: I was just able to get the desired result in the pdf version with the help of \stepcounter{chapter} or `\setcounter{chapter}{8}`

Comment: In my case it was `\setcounter{section}{8}`. Try that if chapter does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do: The curly brackets at the end of a header are not to control section numbering. You can use it to [manually assign an ID to a section header](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html)

e.g. `# Introduction {#intro}`

and/or to [exclude the header from numbering](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-syntax.html#block-level-elements)

e.g. `# Introduction {-}` respectively at the same time `# Introduction {- #intro}`.